# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress)

Tags: java, ios, appium

I am using Appium 1.4.8 for iOS . I have build the code in simulator using xcode and successfully able to launch the server as well as Appium Inspector. But while running my code it is throwing the below error.

My capabilities are 
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.4");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPad 2");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/arunhs/Desktop/AppiumReq/SRC/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ComplianceWire.app");
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

}

```
Error is: 
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 447 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.4', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:44)
at com.selenium.test.DriverScript.setUp(DriverScript.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:590)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:834)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1176)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1101)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1009)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Make sure only one instance of appium server is running on your machine. Close all the appium server, start the server and try again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because the previous session wasn't shutdown properly and it happens when there is exception thrown in your test. Restart the appium server and try it , it should resolve the issue.

Alternatively if you starting appium as node process, you can give option `'--session-override true'` and this would avoid this problem

Comment: I used "--session-override true" but that didn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 2):

If on appium app then select `Override Existing Sessions` checkbox under Settings -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following is working for me. I am testing by connecting Android device. Please make changes as per your need and apply, this should work now.

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().android();
        capabilities.setCapability("no",true);
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 100000);
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy nexus");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", application.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "selendroid");
        capabilities.setCapability("noRest", true);
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: What's the meaning of this?

capabilities.setCapability("no",true);

Answer (score 1):

Adding the deviceName in the capabilities helped.
In the appium logs I could figure out the missing thing.

Answer (score 0):

Kill running servers in the task manager like appium , basically end the task of cmd.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I found was stop the Appium server, Quit it wait for some seconds and again start it and run your script. If needed can do with emulator as well

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error many time. By following simple below steps I was able to fix the issue.

1. Restart eclipse
2. Close your emulator and android studio
3. Quit `appium` on terminal
4. Start the android studio
5. Delete the device and crate new device
6. Now launch the emulator and run the script

Answer (score 0):

I got thie error too. You can solve this by

1. Just stop appium server and close the vs code
2. Cold boot the emulator (I did it from android studio)

The error will get solved now.