# Appium \ MAC OS \ Android \ Java - org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: java, android, macos, testng, appium

I am trying to test Android device on MAC OS X, using Appium (in Java).
The build path includes these:

```
    java-client-<version>.jar
    java-client-<verson>-sources.jar
    selenium-java-<version>.jar
    selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar
```

(the version of the last 2 is the same), and TestNG.

Starting the Appium server (i am using the GUI) works fine and the application (which is already installed on the device) launches. Starting to debug my eclipse project which contains the following lines, i am getting the error for the 3rd line.

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Plus");
    AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

The full error i am getting is:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. Details: Problem getting session data for driver type AndroidDriver; does it implement 'get driverData'?
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that using the GUI launches the application? If that's the case, and what you're showing in code is your full DesiredCapabilities, then your capabilities would be the problem.

You can see what the capabilities the Appium GUI is using at the top with the text "Launching Appium with command".

If you set those flags in your capabilities, then the driver should connect properly.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware of this notion. It still doesn't work. I will attach my code. Please see my answer to myself. I don't know what i am missing.

Comment: I still don't see the "app" capability set for your capabilities (which specifies the .apk to use).

Here's a similar SO question that shows a working DesiredCapabilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048031/org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexception-a-new-session-could-not-be-creat

Comment: I removed all the capabilities from my java code and now it works. I guess the duplication caused it to stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the appium session by use `driver.close()`?

Try to restart your appium server.

P/s: When you **don't want to close driver**, you need enable **Session override** in appium GUI settings or add `--session-override` in appium command line. Then you don't need to restart appium server